# C# BatchUpdateDocumentRequest ReplaceAllText Google Docs Api

Tags: c#, google-api, google-docs

I'm trying to update/replace a given text at a *Google Docs* Template.

The code i've tried so far:

```
DriveService service = GetDriveService();

var firstname = "Firstname";
var lastname = "Lastname";

BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest();

List<Request> requests = new List<Request>();

var repl = new Request();
var substrMatchCriteria = new SubstringMatchCriteria();
var replaceAlltext = new ReplaceAllTextRequest();
replaceAlltext.ReplaceText = firstname + "." + lastname;
substrMatchCriteria.Text = "vorname.nachname";
replaceAlltext.ContainsText = substrMatchCriteria;
repl.ReplaceAllText = replaceAlltext;

requests.Add(repl);
body.Requests = requests;


//Batch update Request requires 3 Parameters
DocumentsResource.BatchUpdateRequest bUpdate = new DocumentsResource.BatchUpdateRequest(service, body, "160NinGjrmshSga8fWkCFRwApV0FTL1BiJCidH7A1yFw");
bUpdate.Execute(); // The Exception is raised here
```

the `DocumentsResource.BatchUpdateRequest`requires the following parameters:
[image]

Following error occurs:

```
Google.GoogleApiException: "Not Found"

JsonReaderException: Error parsing NaN value. Path '', line 1, position 1.

Diese Ausnahme wurde ursprünglich bei dieser Aufrufliste ausgelöst:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumberNaN(Newtonsoft.Json.ReadType, bool)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, bool)
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, bool)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type)
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings)
Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.DeserializeError(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage)
```

I took the *documentId* from the Document path
[image]

Also the file is present using a *files.list*:
[image]

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: Willing to bet thats not the file id.  Do a files.list from google drive api and find the corect file id.  Also whats in GetDriveService

Comment: Added the *files.list* Request, which represents the given *fileId*

Comment: what line is it failing on somethings not found.

Comment: The method `BatchUpdateRequest` expects only two parameters - the request and the document Id, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515870/conditional-formatting-requests-in-google-sheets-in-net-client) for a sample.

Comment: Yes, the `BatchUpdateRequest` for the `Spreadsheet` service.. The `DocsService` expects 3 Parameters

Comment: The third parameter is the OPTIONAL field `writeControl`. The only expected parameters are the `documentId` and the `requests`. I do not know what your variable `service` is but it is unlikely to be one of the required parameters. I assume that it is rather the `resource` to which you want to apply the batch request. Then it should be something like `service.BatchUpdateRequest(body, "160NinGjrmshSga8fWkCFRwApV0FTL1BiJCidH7A1yFw");`  I recommend you to test your request with the [Try it API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate) before C# implementation

Answer (score 2):

First, you can try to generalize the GetService method, I did it because I use various scopes

```
public static object GetService(apiType api = apiType.GDrive)
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        
        string CSPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/MyFolder/");

        using (var stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(CSPath, "client_secret.json"), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {

            string FolderPath = CSPath;

            string FilePath = Path.Combine(FolderPath, "DriveServiceCredentials.json");

            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(FilePath, true)
                ).Result;

        }
        
        if (api == apiType.GDocs)
        {
            DocsService docsService = new DocsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = MyApplicationName,
            });
            return docsService;
        }
        else
        {
            DriveService driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = MyApplicationName
            });
            return driveService;
        }

    }
```

then you can try something like this:

```
public static void EditDoc(string fileId, Dictionary<string, string> textToReplace)
    {
        DocsService service = (DocsService)GetService(apiType.GDocs);
        
        List<Request> requests = new List<Request>();

        foreach (var text in textToReplace)
        {
            var repl = new Request();
            var substrMatchCriteria = new SubstringMatchCriteria();
            var replaceAlltext = new ReplaceAllTextRequest();

            replaceAlltext.ReplaceText = text.Value;
            substrMatchCriteria.Text = text.Key;

            replaceAlltext.ContainsText = substrMatchCriteria;
            repl.ReplaceAllText = replaceAlltext;

            requests.Add(repl);
        }

        BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest { Requests = requests };
        
        service.Documents.BatchUpdate(body, fileId).Execute();

    }
```

I used this document as a reference https://developers.google.com/docs/api/how-tos/merge for some reason Google haven't translated it in C#...