# How do I use the .NET Google Docs API SDK to find and replace text in a given file?

Tags: .net, google-docs-api

Looking for a way to find and replace tokens in a Google Doc using the Docs API via the C#/.NET SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60076057/c-sharp-batchupdatedocumentrequest-replacealltext-google-docs-api) on SO. Here is a code sample in case it helps others:

```
private void mergeText()
        {
            var documentId = "{your Google doc ID}";
            var requests = new List<Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.Request>();
            var repl = new Google.Apis.Docs.v1.Data.Request();
            var substrMatchCriteria = new SubstringMatchCriteria();
            var replaceAlltext = new ReplaceAllTextRequest();

            substrMatchCriteria.Text = "{{foo}}";
            replaceAlltext.ReplaceText = "fizz buzz";            

            replaceAlltext.ContainsText = substrMatchCriteria;
            repl.ReplaceAllText = replaceAlltext;

            requests.Add(repl);

            BatchUpdateDocumentRequest body = new BatchUpdateDocumentRequest { Requests = requests };

            Program.docService.Documents.BatchUpdate(body, documentId).Execute();
        }
```